# twang - Error in Di - crossprod(WX[index, ], X[index, ]) : non-conformable arrays

Tags: propensity-score-matching

I'm trying to build propensity scores with the twang package, but I keep getting this error:
Error in Di - crossprod(WX[index, ], X[index, ]) : non-conformable arrays

I'm attaching the code:

```
ps.TPSV.gbm = ps(Cardioversione ~ Sesso+ age,
                    data = prova)

> ps.TPSV.gbm = ps(Cardioversione ~ Sesso+ age,
+                     data = prova)

Fitting boosted model
Iter   TrainDeviance   ValidDeviance   StepSize   Improve
     1        0.6590             nan     0.0100       nan
     2        0.6581             nan     0.0100       nan
     3        0.6572             nan     0.0100       nan
     4        0.6564             nan     0.0100       nan
     5        0.6556             nan     0.0100       nan
     6        0.6548             nan     0.0100       nan
     7        0.6540             nan     0.0100       nan
     8        0.6533             nan     0.0100       nan
     9        0.6526             nan     0.0100       nan
   
  ...
  
  
  9900        0.4164             nan     0.0100       nan
  9920        0.4161             nan     0.0100       nan
  9940        0.4160             nan     0.0100       nan
  9960        0.4158             nan     0.0100       nan
  9980        0.4157             nan     0.0100       nan
 10000        0.4155             nan     0.0100       nan

Diagnosis of unweighted analysis
Error in Di - crossprod(WX[index, ], X[index, ]) : non-conformable arrays
```

I honestly don't understand which is the problem, the variables are one factorial (Sesso) and one numeric (age), there are no missing values...could anyone help me?

Thank you in advance

I've already tried changing the variables introduced in the PS but there's no way, I tried if the example code works with the lalonde dataset included in twang and it works well.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this error when there is a missing value in the covariate. Can you please run `summary(prova[c("Sesso", "age")])` and post the output to prove there are no missing values?

Comment: You are right Noah, I had 1 missing data in age: `> summary(prova[c("Sesso", "age")])
     Sesso             age        
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :  5.00  
 1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.: 50.00  
 Median :1.0000   Median : 63.00  
 Mean   :0.5719   Mean   : 62.11  
 3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.: 77.00  
 Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :101.00  
                  NA's   :1    `   However..shouldn't the twang package work also with missing data in the covariates? (page 7 if the package instructions). Thank you again

Comment: It should! But no programmer is perfect :)

Comment: :-) thank you again Noah, now it works perfectly. All the best